# Model View Controller implementation in C#

Tags: c#, view, model, controller

I've a question related to some C# implementation on Model-View-Controller. I am fairly new to C#, so I would appreciate some explanations.

I am developing an Windows application. It is build as follows, with Visual Studio. It makes use of the following 3 classes. Program.cs, Controller.cs and mainWindow.cs. When the application starts I want to create a controller that creates a mainWindow and after that the controller should process all data entered in the mainWindow.

```
Program.cs:
static void main() {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    controller.init();
}

Controller.cs
class Controller {

    public void init() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new mainWindow(this));
    }
}

mainWindow.cs
public partial class mainWindow : Form
{
    public mainWindow(Controller parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        parent.closeThisForm();
    }
}
```

So when I try to run this code I get the following error:
Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type '...Controller' is less accessible than method 'abc.mainWindow.mainWindow(abc.Controllers.mainController)'.

I understand that is has to do something with privileges, but don't understand exactly why and what.

Hope anyone can help me with this, (rather simple looking) problem.

Comment: For WinForms you might want to look into MVP as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to make the Controller class public

`public class Controller`

Comment: Thank you all for your reply, I really feel stupid now, was just looking over it.

Comment: Don't worry about it, this exact error has happened to me several times.